Solving a mixed system of 2 cubic and 2 quadratic equations with 4 unknowns
I tried plugging these cubic and quadratic equations into Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab but both said the same thing, too much computing time required. Now I am struggling to solve these equations and I need help on a method to somehow manage to solve them without the brute force method of elimination or substitution. Do I need to possibly simplify them down more? Thanks in advance!
[The system of equations][1]


You miss the proper tag quartics . it is very simple to eliminate all variables but $\beta$ (done by hand).

Could you provide a starting point for this? Do I need to expand everything? I am really stuck still.

There are 6 variables (4 latin, 2 greek) but 4 equations. This cannot be solved as such.

I just want to solve for d, c, alpha, and beta (4 variables). I'm confused which other two variables there are

My fault. There are indeed only 4 variables...

Use Resultant to get quartic equation over $\beta$

The 4 equations are each linear in $c$, so if we solve the first for $c$
$$
c = 14-d(7.6-\alpha)(7.6-\beta)^2;
$$
and insert this into the other three
$$
d(13.92-\alpha)(13.92-\beta)^2+14-d(7.6-\alpha)(7.6-\beta)^2=7 ;
$$
$$
3d7.6^2-7.6(4d\beta+2d\alpha)+7.6[14-d(7.6-\alpha)(7.6-\beta)^2]+d\beta^2+2\alpha\beta d=-1.154 ;
$$
$$
3d13.92^2-13.92(4d\beta+2d\alpha)+13.92[14-d(7.6-\alpha)(7.6-\beta)^2]+d\beta^2+2\alpha\beta d=-0.946 ;
$$
Pushing constants to the right hand sides
$$
d(13.92-\alpha)(13.92-\beta)^2-d(7.6-\alpha)(7.6-\beta)^2=7-14 ;
$$
$$
3d7.6^2-7.6d(4\beta+2\alpha)-7.6d(7.6-\alpha)(7.6-\beta)^2 +d\beta^2+2\alpha\beta d=-1.154-7.6\times 14 ;
$$
$$
3d13.92^2-13.92d(4\beta+2\alpha)-13.92d(7.6-\alpha)(7.6-\beta)^2 +d\beta^2+2\alpha\beta d=-0.946 -13.92\times 14;
$$
To avoid typos set $s\equiv 7.6$, $t\equiv 13.92$,
$$
d(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)^2-d(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)^2=7-14 ;
$$
$$
3s^2 d-sd(4\beta+2\alpha)-sd(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)^2 +d\beta^2+2\alpha\beta d=-1.154-s\times 14 ;
$$
$$
3t^2 d-td(4\beta+2\alpha)-td(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)^2 +d\beta^2+2\alpha\beta d=-0.946 -t\times 14.
$$
All three left hand sides are linear in $d$. Solve the first for $d$
$$
d=\frac{7-14}{(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)^2-(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)^2} ;
$$
and insert this into the other two
$$
\frac{7-14}{(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)^2-(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)^2} [ 3s^2 -s(4\beta+2\alpha)-s(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)^2 +\beta^2+2\alpha\beta ]=-1.154-14 s ;
$$
$$
\frac{7-14}{(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)^2-(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)^2}[3t^2 -t(4\beta+2\alpha)-t(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)^2 +\beta^2+2\alpha\beta ]=-0.946 -14t.
$$
Multiply with the common denominator
$$
3s^2-s^4-4s\beta+2s^3\beta-s^2\beta^2+\beta^2+\alpha(-2s+s^3-2s^2\beta+s\beta^2+2\beta)
$$
$$
=\frac{-1.154-14 s}{7-14}
[t^3-s^3-2t^2\beta+t\beta^2+2s^2\beta-s\beta^2+\alpha(-t^2+2t\beta+s^2-2s\beta)]
;
$$
$$
3t^2-ts^3-4t\beta+2ts^2\beta-ts\beta^2+\beta^2+\alpha(-2t+ts^2-2ts\beta+t\beta^2+2\beta)
$$
$$
=\frac{-0.946 -14t}{7-14}
[t^3-s^3-2t^2\beta+t\beta^2+2s^2\beta-s\beta^2+\alpha(-t^2+2t\beta+s^2-2s\beta)]
$$
This has the structure
$$
f_1(\beta)+f_2(\beta) \alpha = f_3(\beta)+f_4(\beta)\alpha;
$$
$$
g_1(\beta)+g_2(\beta) \alpha = g_3(\beta)+g_4(\beta)\alpha;
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are quadratic functions of $\beta$.
$\alpha$ can be eliminated from these 2 equations:
$$
\alpha= \frac{f_3-f_1}{f_2-f_4} = \frac{g_3-g_1}{g_2-g_4};
$$
A quartic function in $\beta$ remains:
$$
(f_3-f_1)(g_2-g_4)=(g_3-g_1)(f_2-f_4)
$$
Let $1.154=o$, $0.946=n$:
$$
(-s+t)(t^3s^2o+t^3o+42t^3s+2t^2ns-t^2s^3n+t^2so-ts^2n-21ts^3-42ts-2ts^2o-s^3n)/7
$$
$$
-2(-s+t)(14t^3+t^3so+42t^2s+t^2n-s^2t^2n-s^2t^2n+2t^2o+t^2s^2o
-tso-21t-21ts^2+tns-ts^3n-7s^3-2s^2n-s^2o-21s)/7 \beta
$$
$$
+(-s+t)(t^3o+4t^2so-t^2ns+42t^2+21ts+3to+3tn+ts^2o-4ts^2n-42-3so-3ns-21s^2-s^3n)/7 \beta^2
$$
$$
-2(-s+t)(t+s)(to-ns)/7\beta ^3
+(-s+t)(to-7-ns)/7\beta ^4 =0;
$$
Inserting the constants $n,s,t,o$ in our case this is
$$
1.692\beta^4-344.837\beta^3+13662\beta^2-180278\beta+751245 =0.
$$
Eliminating common factors:
$$
(t^3s^2o+t^3o+42t^3s+2t^2ns-t^2s^3n+t^2so-ts^2n-21ts^3-42ts-2ts^2o-s^3n)
$$
$$
-2(14t^3+t^3so+42t^2s+t^2n-s^2t^2n-s^2t^2n+2t^2o+t^2s^2o
-tso-21t-21ts^2+tns-ts^3n-7s^3-2s^2n-s^2o-21s) \beta
$$
$$
+(t^3o+4t^2so-t^2ns+42t^2+21ts+3to+3tn+ts^2o-4ts^2n-42-3so-3ns-21s^2-s^3n)\beta^2
$$
$$
-2(t+s)(to-ns)\beta ^3
+(to-7-ns)\beta ^4 =0.
$$
This seems to be as good as it gets. For our $t,o,n,s$ this has the 4 solutions $\beta=8.6706, 12.480, 26.229, 156.42$.
Part of this solution has been computed using Maple as an AI tool.
